# When to use CTE in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

```
SELECT 
    tchart.*
INTO
    #OrderSections
FROM 
    Order.Charts tchart
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT  
        tchart.ID,
        tchart.ORCode,
        tchart.SectionalDistance,
        row_number() OVER( PARTITION BY rrs.ORCode ORDER BY tchart.VendorTimestampUTC DESC, tchart.InsertedTimestampUTC DESC, tchart.ID DESC ) AS RecordIndex
    FROM
        #OrderStaging rrs
    INNER JOIN
        Order.Charts tchart
    ON
        rrs.ORCode = tchart.ORCode
    ) AS Latest_tchart
ON
    tchart.ID = Latest_tchart.ID
WHERE
    Latest_tchart.RecordIndex   = 1;
```

---

```
    With cte as(    
    SELECT  
        tchart.ID,
        tchart.ORCode,
        tchart.SectionalDistance,
        row_number() OVER( PARTITION BY rrs.ORCode ORDER BY tchart.VendorTimestampUTC DESC, tchart.InsertedTimestampUTC DESC, tchart.ID DESC ) AS RecordIndex
    FROM
        #OrderStaging rrs
    INNER JOIN
        Order.Charts tchart
    ON
        rrs.ORCode = tchart.ORCode) 
    SELECT 
        cte.*
    INTO
        #OrderSections
    FROM 
        cte
    WHERE 
        RecordIndex = 1
```

Would the CTE have a great impact specially in a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

To answer a question about performance and execution plans, you should look at the particular plans for your queries.

However, I would expect the query to have the same execution plan, regardless of whether the logic is in a subquery or a CTE.  This is true in SQL Server, but not other databases.  For instance, Postgres materializes CTEs, so you would expect a performance difference.

EDIT:

CTEs are needed for hierarchical queries (recursive CTEs).  For other queries, they are a convenience -- and can be very convenient because you can refer to the CTE multiple times in the same query.  But, they don't have a specific impact on the execution plan in SQL Server.  The CTE is substituted into the query and the whole processing is optimized as once.

Comment: When CTE will matters?